# Selectable, draggable and droppable elements with AngularJS

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs

I've been working on a demo for selectable, draggable and droppable elements with AngularJS.

http://plnkr.co/edit/rSxklI?p=preview

I have the functionality I want working correctly, however I'm pretty sure I haven't done some of it the angular way.

In dndCtrl I'm setting a scope variable selected which is populated when elements are selected.  draggable and droppable use this scope variable to count the number of selected items and to push/slice the selected items when dropped.  Is this a good idea?  Can I use ng-model instead?

I'm also using jquery to select the .ui-selected classes in the selectable directive.  Is there an angular way to get the selected items?

Credits to methylene for the gist i based this off, https://gist.github.com/methylene/4409488

Answer (score 0):

I don't know more about this but, Any way if you remove 
     http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css
from your script. it is working. This may helps you to fix it.

Comment: The bootstrap css is styling the buttons.  What do you mean it works when you remove it?

Comment: The functionality shouldn't be affected by the css.  Can you be more specific about what isn't working for you?  Browser?

Answer (score 0):

The Angular equivalent of $('selector') is `angular.element('selector');`

I would recommend having a look at the Angular Bootstrap code (like the Accordion) to see the Angular way of interaction between components. https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap

Comment: Thanks for this comment, I really should have been looking at how they were developing those directives.  I've done almost a complete rewrite since I asked this question.  The plunker is updated if anyone is interested.